# Can sys.stdout.write() and raw_input() been done together?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to build my first text-based game in Python 2.7. However, I'm having some trouble with getting input. I want to use `sys.stdout.write()` to make it look more retro, but I want it to wait for input after it finished printing. When I try to do the `raw_input()` thing, it prints fine, but in the place where it should wait for input, it prints `None` instead.

```
import sys
import time

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        time.sleep(.04)

answer = raw_input(print_slow("Do you wish to begin? (Y/n)"))
```

Comment: `raw_input` takes a string as a prompt. Your slowprinting function doesn't return a string, it returns nothing so you get `None` as a prompt.

Comment: You probably want to call `print_slow(my_string)` *and then* call `raw_input`.

Comment: `print_slow("Do you wish to begin? (Y/n)"); raw_input()` basically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random None when printing from raw\_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922537/random-none-when-printing-from-raw-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two challenges you are facing

1. `raw_input` accepts a string to print, but your function returns `None`.
2. Your output is likely line-buffered so you probably would not see any output anyway.

The solution to the first issue was mentioned in the comments to the question.  The solution to the second is simply to flush your output between writing each letter.

```
import sys
import time

def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()  # Force writing to screen even though newline has not been reached.
        time.sleep(.04)

print_slow("Do you wish to begin? (Y/n)")
answer = raw_input()
```