# In raw_input() appears at the end "none"

Tags: python-2.x

By printing out of raw_input() appears at the end a "none".

I defined above a function to look nice when printing the question.

Here's my code:

```
def delay_print_input(string):
  for c in string:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.15)

ans=raw_input(delay_print_input("What do you want?\n>> "))
```

The output looks like:

```
What do you want?
>> None
```

My question is, how can I remove this none?

Comment: Because your function is returning  `None`

Comment: you should use a return statement in the end of the function that you have defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random None when printing from raw\_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922537/random-none-when-printing-from-raw-input)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns None, which `raw_input` then prints. What you want is this:

```
def delay_print_input(string):
  for c in string:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.15)

delay_print_input("What do you want?\n>> ")
ans=raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning None and sending it to the input function. You can just return a blank string in your function

```
def delay_print_input(string):
    for c in string:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.15)
    return ""
```