# Output ends in none when delaying text

Tags: python, delay

I am trying to make a text-based adventure game.  I am new to Python
and I am trying to delay the text like in the older games.

```
from time import sleep
import sys
def de(string):
    for c in string:
        print(c, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.1)
```

Throughout the code, do things like:

```
print(de("\nPlayer health: "), player_health,)
```

or

```
user_fighter = input(de("what is the name of your fighter?"))
```

The output always ends in "None"

e.g.
`Player health: None 100`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Can you provide us more info about your program output and some examples?

Comment: Please confirm that adding a line after the definition of the de() function in your question e.g. `print de(“Player Health:“)` will print `Player Health:None` ? Please check this then edit this into your question to make your question a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What? How does the code you show produce `**None**` Or, @d_kennetz what are you doing changing this significant aspect of the question?

Comment: The value your `de()` function returns is `None` which is why you see that value being printed. Just call `de()` directly (i.e. not as an argument in a `print()` call).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random None when printing from raw\_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922537/random-none-when-printing-from-raw-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `de` function does not return anything, and therefore has a return value of `None`.  Additionally, you already have a `print` within the function that does what you're trying to do.  As a result, you can call the `de` function directly instead of calling it within a `print`.

## Code

```
from time import sleep
import sys
def de(string):
    for c in string:
        print(c, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.1)
# ...
# Code
# ...

de("\nPlayer health: ")
print(player_health)
```

## Output

`Player health: 100`

"Player health" is displayed letter by letter, and the value is displayed at once after.

Answer (score 0):

How about having two functions. One that outputs text and another that output text but returns a user's entry.

```
from time import sleep
import sys

def de(string, end='\n'):
    for c in string:
        print(c, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.1)
    print(end,end='')

def de_input(string):
    de(string, end='')
    return input()

de("Welcome to game")
name = de_input("What is your name?")

de("Welcome %s" % name)
```