# Crawl makes input release "None" | Python

Tags: python, function, input, printing

So I definitely know that saying this:

`x = input(print('hello what is ur name uwu:')`

Would produce:

`hello what is ur name uwu:None`

But here is my code:

```py
import sys
import time
from colorama import Fore

def crawl(text,ti):
  for char in text:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(ti)

input(crawl(Fore.RED + 'Well, hello there my dear player!',0.1))
```

and as expected... it produces:

`Well, hello there my dear player!None`

I tried doing this:

`crawl(input(Fore.RED + 'Well, hello there my dear player!'),0.1)`

and it produces correctly but there is one problem... it produces it instantaneously and my crawl function should drag it out letter by letter. Please help.

Comment: How about separate lines `crawl(...)` and `input()`.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: I described it at answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random None when printing from raw\_input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922537/random-none-when-printing-from-raw-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

built-in `input` function will print arguments if they are given.

> The prompt string, if given, is printed to standard output without a
>       trailing newline before reading input.

So you shouldn't give arguments to `input`.
You can simply separate calling `crawl` and `input`.

Note: I removed `colorama` dependency since it is not relevant with your question.

```py
import sys
import time


def crawl(text, ti):
    for char in text:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(ti)


crawl('Well, hello there my dear player!', 0.1)
x = input()
print(x)
```

output:

```
Well, hello there my dear player!5
5
```

5 was my std input.