# slowtyping in python with the following code

Tags: python

```
import time, random, sys

def print(s):
  for c in s + '\n':
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1./20)

print("\nHello,\n")
print("You can choose out of 5 tasks : ")
print("task 1 | add 3 numbers")
print("task 2 | multiple numbers")
print("task 3 | enter a number between 10 and 20")
print("task 4 | count until 200")
print("task 5 | guess the number")

x = int(input(print("\nWhich tasks do you want to preform? | ")))
```

when i use this code, it wil type "none" after its done typing x.
can anyone explain to me why that happens? and how i can fix it.
or how i can slow type a input.
(its part of a bigger code, but this are the first couple lines of code)

Comment: Remove the print statement inside of the input: `x = int(input("\nWhich tasks do you want to perform? | "))`

Comment: Better duplicate target (see also linked questions): [Random None when printing from raw_input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26922537/7851470)

Answer (score 0):

> when i use this code, it wil type "none" after its done typing x. can anyone explain to me why that happens?

This is because you use `input()` incorrectly. [From the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> input([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Since your custom `print()` function has no `return` statement, it returns `None` by default and that value is passed to `input()` as the "prompt" which `input()` then prints out.

Also, Python already has a function named `print()`. Using the same name as a built-in Python function will lead to pain and suffering, so don't do it. In fact, you don't need to write a `print()` function at all, since this functionality is already built in.

In otherwords, you can get the same behavior with:

```
input('Which tasks do you want to preform? | ')
```

Alternatively, you can call `input()` without any parameter:

```
x = int(input())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reaction. If i remove the print, which im gonna give a different def, then the input will not slowprint anymore, which is what i wanted. Is there a way to slowprint a input?

Comment: @MatheunStruik I think your two options are to call `input()` without a parameter or to write your own version of `input()` that reads from stdin.

Comment: @MatheunStruik use your custom print function before getting the input. Like this: `print("..."); x=int(input()) `

Comment: @Code-Apprentice do you maybe know a custom input i can use, i cant find any

Comment: @MatheunStruik By "custom", I mean write it yourself similar to the way you wrote your own `print()`. I think for your purposes, using the standard `input()` with no parameters works just fine.